# Peewee 3 - Python - Rank query results

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I have a self-referencing db table with notes (id, title, parent).
[Note: the self-referencing property of the table is not relevant to the question]
I would like to order them alphabetically by title and find the rank (= order) of a specific note by its `id`. I'm using Peewee 3 as ORM.

**DB Model:**

```
class Note(Model):
    title = CharField()
    parent = ForeignKeyField('self', backref='children', null = True)
```

**Code:**

```
noteAlias = Note.alias()
subquery = (noteAlias.select(noteAlias.id, fn.RANK().over(partition_by=[noteAlias.title], order_by=[noteAlias.title]).alias('rank')).where(noteAlias.parent.is_null()).alias('subq'))
query = (Note.select(subquery.c.id, subquery.c.rank).from_(subquery).where(subquery.c.id == 5))
print("Rank of element is: " + str(query.rank))
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

**SQLite test**
If I simply run this sqlite code directly against my db:

```
SELECT (title, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY title) AS placement) FROM note
```

I get the error: `near ",": syntax error:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of SQLite perhaps doesn't support window functions, as this was added relatively recently in 3.25 I believe.

Comment: Fist of all: thank you very much for your help, it is much appreciated. You are right, I came to the same conclusion. My SQLite version is 3.11, but window functions are supported only since 3.25. I am running Linux Mint 18.3 (fully updated) and I've tried Mint 19.3 (latest release) but in both cases SQLite version is < 3.25. I'm developing an open source software in Python GTK3. I suppose I could install un unstable version of the sqlite3 package in my pc (don't know how); but in any case, my software wouldn't be available in the Mint Software Manager and end-users would have to do the same.

Comment: Wait... coleifer/peewee... you are THAT coleifer ??!!?? Sorry =) Thank you very much for your awesome work. Peewee is absolutely great!!

Comment: You can try statically-linking a custom build of sqlite with a python driver: https://github.com/coleifer/pysqlite3#building-a-statically-linked-library -- peewee will use pysqlite3 if it's available.